# Vertices with indexArray doesn't connect triangles properly

Tags: javascript, indexing, processing, p5.js, vertex

I'm trying to create  a sort of "polygon drawer" in p5.js.
My intented behaviour is that a random triangle out of three vertices gets ctreated at start and the user can use his mouse to add triangles, which automatically connect to the two closest vertices from the mouseCursor.
This allw orks fine, but sometimes when I start adding the new vertice by clicking (the current vector at the mouse get's pushed to the array of vertices and the triangle / index array get' updated), a triangle get's drawn which uses a different vertice, not the closest, second closest and the mouse cursor vector.

I have two arrays for the vertices and triangles (the later functions as an index array):

```
let vertices = [];
let triangles = [];
```

Globally I track the closest and second closest index of the vertices array:

```
let closest;
let secondClosest;
```

I start by creating a random triangle. I push each vertex' index to the triangle array and push the first one once again to complete the triangle:

```
function createRandomTriangle(){
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
   let vert = createVector(random(0, width),random(0, height));
    vertices.push(vert);
    triangles.push(i);
  }
  triangles.push(0);
}
```

In my draw function I first draw every triangle by going through the triangles array and drawing lines from their vector equivalents in the vertices array.

I then calculate which two vertices are closest to the mouse cursor and update my globals.

As the last step I draw the trianlge from the mouse cursor as some sort of "guide".

```
function draw() {
  background(255);

  for(i = 0; i < triangles.length-1; i++){
    line(vertices[triangles[i]].x, vertices[triangles[i]].y,vertices[triangles[i+1]].x, vertices[triangles[i+1]].y);
  }

  let mouseVector = createVector(mouseX, mouseY);

  let distances = [];
  for(i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++){
    distances.push(mouseVector.dist(vertices[i]));
  }
  closest = distances.indexOf(Math.min( ...distances ));    
  distances[closest] = width + height;
  secondClosest = distances.indexOf(Math.min( ...distances ));

  line(mouseVector.x, mouseVector.y, vertices[closest].x, vertices[closest].y);
  line(mouseVector.x, mouseVector.y, vertices[secondClosest].x, vertices[secondClosest].y);
  line(vertices[closest].x, vertices[closest].y, vertices[secondClosest].x, vertices[secondClosest].y); 
    }
```

Now this function is probably the one causing harm, but I can't figure out why.

Once the user clicks, the mouse cursor vector get's pushed to the array of vertices, his index is pushed first to the triangles array, then the closest index, then the second closest index, then the mouse cursor index again.

```
function mouseClicked() { 
    let latestIndex = vertices.push(createVector(mouseX, mouseY)) - 1;
    triangles.push(latestIndex);
    triangles.push(closest);
    triangles.push(secondClosest);
    triangles.push(latestIndex);
}
```

Sometimes this method works fine and sometimes a new line suddenly appears.

I can't comprehend exactly why.

You can test thje p5.js sketch here: https://editor.p5js.org/etlam/sketches/4SAhIydAC

Comment: You've based your triangles array on the way you're drawing them, adding 4 points to it each time a new triangle is created. When you're drawing them however you do not iterate over it in groups of 4, which means your draw method connects the 1st (and thus also 4th) point of a triangle to the 1st point of the next triangle. You can fix this the fast way by putting `if (i % 4 != 3)` before the `line()` command. A better solution is to create an array of three points for each triangle and push that to the triangles array, then use a nested loop to draw them.

Comment: `let distanceBetween2Points = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x_coord_1-x_coord_2, 2)+Math.pow(y_coord_1-y_coord_2, 2));`

Comment: @Chris G: That makes sense! I'm dumb man. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not do like `ctx.lineTo(x, y); ctx.closePath()`?

Comment: @z1on [Delaunay triangulation](https://editor.p5js.org/allison.parrish/sketches/BkhEmKKjW) looks similar to what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic example of how you might go about drawing a polygon. I really recommend creating a StateMaker, so you can keep track of everything, but that's more than I'm willing to go into right now.

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */ 
let doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q;
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
rand = (min, max)=>{
  let mn = min, mx = max;
  if(mx === undefined){
    mx = mn; mn = 0;
  }
  return mn+Math.floor(Math.random()*(mx-mn+1));
}
// tiny library above magic below - can put on another page using a load Event (besides // end load line)
const can = I('can'), canB = can.getBoundingClientRect();
const canW = can.width = canB.width, canH = can.height = canB.height;
const ctx = can.getContext('2d'), points = [];
ctx.lineWidth = '1px'; ctx.lineStyle = '#000'; ctx.fillStyle = '#700';
function polyFun(e){
  let b = can.getBoundingClientRect();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canW, canH);
  points.push([e.clientX-b.left, e.clientY-b.top]);
  ctx.beginPath(); ctx.moveTo(...points[0]);
  for(let i=1,l=points.length; i<l; i++){
    ctx.lineTo(...points[i]);
  }
  ctx.fill(); ctx.stroke(); ctx.closePath();
}
if(mobile){
  ontouchstart = e=>{
    polyFun(e.touches[0]);
  }
}
else{
  onmousedown = polyFun;
}
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; font-size:0; padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body,#can{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
#can{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <canvas id='can'></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```